# Problema no angular 1.5 rodando com arquivos minificados

Tags: angularjs

Tenho um projeto com angularjs 1.5 rodando na minha máquina modo debug, fui gerar uma release então executei o gulp para minificar os arquivos e começaram os problemas fiz diversos ajustes e agora estou com esse erro:
    "Error: [$sce:unsafe] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$sce/unsafe"

Não sei o que fazer pois no arquivo normal funciona e no minificado não, alguém sabe que erro é este?

Comment: Você está usando alguma coisa assim `ng-bind-html=...` no seu projeto?

Comment: Tenho um trecho que uso sim, eu estava lendo agora que isso talvez pode dar erro, se for o caso qual a melhor maneira de usá-lo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é causado quando você tenta aplicar um bind de texto em modo html, ou seja `ng-bind-html` sem a utilização do módulo `ngSanitize`, que é o responsável por 'lapidar', digamos assim, esse texto para o mesmo seja exibido.

Existem alguns "fixes" que você cria uma diretiva para contornar esse erro de modo que você aplica o `bind` de modo "unsafe". Mas o modo mais correto seria de inicializar o módulo `ngSanitize` do próprio Angular em sua aplicação. É uma inicialização comum como a de qualquer outro módulo.

```
//Inclua o script como achar melhor, ex.:
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

e em seu módulo faça a inicialização:

```
angular.module('app', [
    //Seus outros módulos aqui
    'ngSanitize'
]);
```

---

**Editado**

Como essas opções (e nossa conversa nos comentários) não resolveram o problema - o que é bem estranho - esse aqui seria o fix alternativo que mencionei:

```
angular.module('gaxApp')
.filter('trust_html', ['$sce', function($sce){
    return function(text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };
}]);
```

Sendo usado assim:

```
ng-bind-html="seucampo | trust_html"
```

Comment: Eu estou fazendo isso por isso que estou achando estranho! Eu coloco o "ngSanitize" na inicialização e importo a versão dele via CDN

Comment: @DiogoSoares como você está fazendo o bind? consegue colocar o código como exemplo?

Comment: A inicialização do módulo está assim:
    ` angular
    .module('gaxApp', [
      'ngAnimate',
      'ngResource',
      'ngSanitize'
    ])`
No meu html está assim: 
    `<div data-ng-bind-html="fornecimentoCtrl.breadcrumb"></div>`

Comment: @DiogoSoares Tente remover o `data-` do bind. Se não resolver, tente assim: `ng-bind-html-unsafe`

Comment: coloquei o ng-bind-html-unsafe não apresentou o erro porém também não mostrou o valor, não tinha passado por essa antes, hehehehe

Comment: @DiogoSoares cara, que estranho... Vou editar a resposta com um fix alternativo..

Comment: para esse caso do ng-bind-html eu consegui agora colocando o $sce  no controller ai coloquei o meu html dentro do método $sce.trustAsHtml porém não funcionou para os .components que tenho na tela é uma boa prática usar o $sce?

Comment: @DiogoSoares Confesso que nunca precisei usar. Bastava adicionar o módulo `sanitize` que resolvia o problema. Não sei por que o seu não está funcionando... Estranho.. Mas já vi alguns exemplos usando o $sce, que também foi o que fiz na edição de minha resposta, porém de modo mais dinâmico.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema que fazia o ngSanitize não funcionar.
O problema acontecia porque eu estava carregando a página de login sem o ngSanitize a após efetuar o login eu chamada outra página que ai sim carregava porém os ng-apps tinham o mesmo nome e por algum motivo o ngSanitize não era inicializado, separei tudo certinho com outros nomes e está funcionando 100% agora.
Obrigado pela ajuda!!!