# Como permitir a execução de tags html a partir de uma variável em angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estou consumindo dados de uma api utilizando angular, a api está me retornando o seguinte valor com HTML:

```
variavel = '<p>testo de retorno</p>';
```

Quando eu faço a exibição na view tipo {{variavel}} 
é interpretado tudo como string exibindo o HTML.
Preciso exibir apenas o texto considerando as tags HTML, ou seja, não posso remover a HTML. Tem que exibir apenas o texto e interpretar o HTML.

Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso utilizando angular?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no ngBindHtml https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml. O angular trata o HTML para evitar ataque de XSS.

Comment: valeu cara. Estou verificando isso agora

Comment: @MiguelBatista talvez você se depare com alguns erros (como $sce) de ao usar `ng-bind-html`. Isso acontece pela ausência do módulo `ngSanitize`. Respondi outro usuário com este problema aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/132005/problema-no-angular-1-5-rodando-com-arquivos-minificados

Comment: Eu consegui resolver aqui. Vou postar a resposta e realmente me deparei com esse erro referente ao $sce

Comment: @CelsomTrindade eu consegui resolver sem o ngSanitize. Apenas com a dependência do $sce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize o ngBindHtml, no exemplo logo a baixo o conteúdo da variável `$scope.myHtml` vai ser injetado dentro da `<div>`.

#### HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-bind-html="myHtml"></div>
</div>
```

#### Controller

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.myHtml = '<p>testo de retorno</p>';
});
```

Caso precise do exemplo prático para esclarecer:  https://jsfiddle.net/lucassilvax/du9ynoag/

Answer (score 1):

Como estou pegando os dados via Ajax se tentar exibir as informações diretamente a partir da directiva ng-bind-html é reportado erro referente ao $sce ["Error: [$sce:unsafe] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$sce/unsafe"](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce). Então
consegui resolver o problema da seguinte forma de acordo com a referência: 
[Problema no angular 1.5 rodando com arquivos minificados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/132005/problema-no-angular-1-5-rodando-com-arquivos-minificados)

```
const angular = require('angular');
const ngRoute = require('angular-route');   

class ProdutoController{
        /* ngInject */
        constructor($scope,$routeParams, $sce){
          this.$scope = $scope;
          this.$sce = $sce;
          this.$routeParams = $routeParams;

        }

        $onInit() {
          this.produto = [];

        }

        $onInit() {
          this.produto = [];
          this.carregaProduto();

        }

        async carregaProduto() {
          const produto = await Promise.all([this.services.produto.get(this.$routeParams.id)]);
          this.$scope.descricao_produto = this.$sce.trustAsHtml(produto.descricao);

          this.$scope.$apply(() => {
            this.produto = produto;
          });


        }

    }
```

**Linha da resolução:**

```
this.$scope.descricao_produto = this.$sce.trustAsHtml(produto.descricao);
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-bind-html="descricao_produto"></div>
```

Comment: o modo como você fez aqui resolve, mas lembre-se que ele foi aplicado localmente, ou seja, se você precisar de outro ajax que tenha exibição de texto em html (como um portal de notícias), o ideal seria usar o modulo ngSanitize, para não precisar de muito trabalho manual. Mas claro.. Cada caso é um caso e depende da sua necessidade. Apenas uma observação a ser feita. =D

Comment: Entendi. Vou mudar e colocar o módulo 'ngSanitize' como dependência. Não tinha assimilado essa diferença. vlw.